# Precision is lost when writing 16-bit color to 8-bit sRGB framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

Firstly I want to say is that no matter which graphics API you use. I want to know how it's generally working.

As I understand, when sRGB framebuffer receives color, it gamma corrects it and then writes it to the buffer. But what if we're using HDR rendering (several intermediate 16-bit framebuffers), and then, at the final blit pass, writing that 16-bit value to an sRGB 8-bit framebuffer?
16-bit framebuffers are good, because they give more precision to the color. But does the above conversion just cancel that improved precision? What happens first? Firstly gamma correction then narrowing 16-bit to 8-bit or vice versa? As I understand it's better to gamma correct 16-bit values, not 8-bit, because it saves precision in the dark areas, thus reducing color banding. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: What operation are you using to write a "16-bit color" to an sRGB image?

Comment: @NicolBolas it's just a blit pass. It uses 16-bit framebuffer as a shader uniform, and renders it to the final 8-bit sRGB framebuffer. All it does is copying the color data.

Comment: If you're doing a rendering operation, reading shaders and writing values, it's not "just a blit pass"; it's a *rendering operation*. This means that you don't convert 16-bit values to sRGB; you load 16-bit values into shader variables, which then get written to the framebuffer using whatever hardware and settings are used to handle fragment shader outputs.

Comment: @NicolBolas actually I understand that I don't convert 16-bit values to sRGB. It can be done automatically when writing to an sRGB framebuffer. As I said, all it does is just copying the color data. Renders the content of the HDR framebuffer to the sRGB framebuffer. I'm interested in what order that write operation coverts and narrows the data (as I asked in the post above). And does really that order matter? (Can I get any more precision (to reduce color banding) if the gamma correction will be applied on 16-bit data, before narrowing to 8-bit?)

Comment: "*in what order that write operation coverts and narrows the data (as I asked in the post above).*" The same order it would for anything else. The shader does not have "16-bit values". It does not write "16-bit values". Unless you're using an extension, GLSL doesn't allow you to have 16-bit values of any kind. What you read from the texture is converted at read-time into 32-bit floats. *That* is what gets written to the output, and it will be treated exactly as if you had computed that value by any other means.

Comment: "The same order it would for anything else." ..? Well. When I output any color information and trying to write it to a render target that has a slightly different format in which it stores color... It somehow should convert it, as well as gamma correction should be applied there (if using an sRGB framebuffer). And I don't really know "how it would" for anything else.

Comment: "The shader does not have "16-bit values". It does not write "16-bit values". Unless you're using an extension, GLSL doesn't allow you to have 16-bit values of any kind."... As I remember OpenGL has a thing like precision that can be specified. Also DirectX has half data type which is 16-bit float. And I didn't want to know how it happens in shaders, because I know how it does. I'm interested in how a graphics API does things that is not visible to me. The things that occurs after the pixel shader is executed. How it writes to a render target in the situation I've described.

Comment: My point is that how you got the data that you write to the fragment shader output is *irrelevant*. Whether you read it from an 8-bit texture, a 16-bit texture, got it from an interpolated fragment shader input, computed it from some math, or some combination of the above, at the moment you write it in the FS, it is a 32-bit floating-point number. That is the first conversion that happens. The hardware will not treat it any differently regardless of how you got the value.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand what you're trying to say. You don't like the title of the question. But I think it's not irrelevant how I get the data I write to the FS output. What I was talking about is about the color data, not the storage in will be in. When you firstly calculate the data in 16-bit and then it sampled from the framebuffer texture to a 32-bit float shader variable, the color data doesn't suddenly become high-quality, as if it could be calculated in 32-bit in the first place.